# RoR3: nested namespace routes, undefined method error

Tags: namespaces, ruby-on-rails-3, activescaffold

I am using namespace routes to create an admin section.

The problem is that the moment I moved un-namespaced and working controllers into the /admin namespace, I suddenly get an **undefined methods error.**

```
Showing 

/media/_portable_/appname/vendor/plugins/active_scaffold/frontends/default/views/_form_messages.html.erb where line #4 raised:

undefined method `errors' for :record:Symbol
Extracted source (around line #4):

1: <%= render :partial => 'messages' %>
2: 
3: <% unless @record.nil? %>
4:     <%= error_messages_for :record, :object_name => @record.class.model_name.human.downcase %>
5: <% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
 namespace :admin do 
    root :controller => 'dashboard', :action => "index"
    resources :dashboard, :users, :apps do
      as_routes
    end
    resources :admin_sessions, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]
  end
```

Any help on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/vhochstein/active_scaffold/issues/closed#issue/57